# How to check type of React event inside a method?

Tags: reactjs

I have a handler like below:

```
  function touchMouseMove(
    e: TouchEvent<HTMLDivElement> | MouseEvent<HTMLDivElement>
  ) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (!mouseDown) return;
    if (e instanceof TouchEvent) var position = e.touches[0].clientY;
    else var position = e.clientY;
    var diff = position - currentPosition;

    document.getElementById(targetId)!.style.height = lastClientY + diff + 'px';
  }
  }
```

and I want to check inside a method what is the event type. Above throws an error in

```
    else var position = e.clientY;
```

For some reason this `else` statement does not assume that `e` must be a `MouseEvent` then. How to fix that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### To answer all your questions(3):

1. to check the type of any variable you can use `typeof` identifier.

**Example:**

```
const exampleVairable = ['test']

console.log('example variable is type:', typeof exampleVariable)
```

2. If you need to cast a type, you can use the `as` identifier

**Example:**

```
const example = ''

console.log(example as string)
```

3. You are getting the error because ts cannot determine which type is being used since it can be mouse or event, to solve this you just have to cast it or let it know what type you are expecting (see code below)

### Solution

```
function touchMouseMove(
  e: TouchEvent<HTMLDivElement> | MouseEvent<HTMLDivElement>
) {
  e.preventDefault();
  if (!mouseDown) return;

  let position: number;

  if (e instanceof TouchEvent) {
    position = e.touches[0].clientY;
  } else {
    position = (e as MouseEvent<HTMLDivElement>).clientY;
  }

  const diff = position - currentPosition;

  document.getElementById(targetId)!.style.height = lastClientY + diff + 'px';
}
```